# Piping keystrokes to command line program and System.Console.get_KeyAvailable() exception

Tags: c#, command-line, exception, pipe

I am trying to automate a command line program (which I believe was written in C#) in Windows 7. When I run the program and type the input manually, it runs fine. However, when I try to pipe in the same input from a text file (ie. `type input.txt | Program123.exe`) I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot see if a key has b
een pressed when either application does not have a console or when console inpu
t has been redirected from a file. Try Console.In.Peek.
   at System.Console.get_KeyAvailable()
   at Program123.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This occurs when its waiting for the user to press any key to exit the program.

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much says it all. The program does not support piped or redirected input. The reason is that when the program is waiting for a keypress, it is reading the key presses directly instead of reading from stdin.

I think you could use a program like [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) instead.

Comment: Yea, I would consider using AutoIT but I may need to get approval to use it. I was hoping that something could be done using an open source product or some kind of C# program I can write myself.